# Variable passed in from REST API into build pipeline yml is not getting picked up correctly

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have Azure DevOps build pipeline yml that has parameters, variables defined and at the same time I have an external tool that kicks of the jobs in the yml including passing in some parameters. At first I thought the parameters in the yml and incoming parameters should be the same, so I lined up all the names to match. Only to find out that the incoming parameters through REST API is actually a variable!

```
parameters:
  - name: machineList
    type: string
    default: any
```

then I have variable declared like so

```
variables:
  testsettingsjson: ${{ parameters.machineList }}
```

From the REST API that get's passed in and when I query the request coming in, calling the get build data api, I see

```
"parameters" : "{ \"machineList\" : \"machine1\" }"
```

Now trying to use the variable it works in some places and not in others.

```
  - script: |
      echo "Output variable values"
      echo "ML json : '$(testsettingsjson)'"
      echo "ML json : '$(machineList)'"
      echo "ML json variables : '${{ variables.machineList }}'"
```

the output I see for the above is :

```
Output variable values
ML json : any
ML json : machine1
ML json variables:
```

So $(machineList) works, I thought.

```
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Read ML input value'
        inputs:
          targetType: filePath
          filePath: ./ReadMachineList.ps1
        continueOnError: true
        env:
          TESTSETTINGSJSON: $(machineList)
```

When I read TESTSETTINGSJSON using $env:TESTSETTINGSJSON from the powershell script above, the value is "any"!

I am super confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found a work around by reading MACHINELIST directly but it doesn't explain the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. To make it work, I first structured my solution working with 3 separate set of "variables", here's an example.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: MachineList
    type: string
    default: any
```

```yaml
variables:
  ${{ if ne(variables['machineList'], '') }}:
    machinelist: $(machineList)
  ${{ if ne(parameters.MachineList, 'Any') }}:
    machinelist: ${{ parameters.MachineList }}
```

- MachineList is the input to the pipeline.
- machineList is the input value from Power Automate (or REST API).
- machinelist is the local variable in yml.

Now in the rest of the yml, I can use $(machinelist) switching between the values for the pipeline versus the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

> Only to find out that the incoming parameters through REST API is
> actually a variable!

This is as expected. The `parameters` you specify in the request body of the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) actually represents the variable. If you want to replace the runtime parameter, you should use `templateParameters` instead.

[image]

```
$json= @'
        {
          "templateParameters": {
            "machineList": "machine1"
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hugh Lin. The input is actually passed in via Power Automate, so it's not something that can be modified. So my question remains, how to setup the pipeline such that between the parameters specified in the yml and the parameters coming in via the API the correct values are used. 

I setup the parameters in yml as a way to manually test the functionality before enabling the connection from Power Automate.